# GPS module for Netduino Plus 2

Tags: .net, embedded, .net-micro-framework, .net-cf-3.5

I am working with the Netduino plus 2 which runs off the .NET micro framework. The board has worked well for all my applications.

Recently, I integrated  GPS capability to the board using a 20 Channel EM-406A SiRF III Receiver with Antenna GPS module capable of communicating over a serial interface.

However, I am not able to obtain a fix indoors. Obtaining a fix indoors is important to me even if it takes the GPS module 30 mins to obtain a fix. I am getting GPS data through the serial interface just fine. I understand that getting a GPS fix is not easy indoors and GPS satellite signals are weak but, I do know that there are GPS module that can obtain a fix indoors even though they take several minutes to obtain that fix. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,

Subbu

Comment: Why was this topic closed? There is a separate sub section on embedded development and .net micro framework on stack overflow which fits into the category of my question. I also got an answer to my question. I understand that I asked a question about hardware but embedded software development encompasses working closely with hardware as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the sensitivity of the GPS receiver being used as well as the gain of the antenna used with the latter item most likely to be the most critical here. Antenna design is a non-trivial issue and due to the fact that GPS signals will easily be attenuated when having to travel through any material at all, then this is not something you might be able to resolve using off the shelf parts without the assistance of an RF engineer.